# Laplace's equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, boundary-value-problem

I have three boundary value problems.

1. Find common solution of boundary value problem for Laplace's equation in a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
   $
   \begin{cases}
   \Delta u = 0 & \text{ if r $<$ 1} \\
   u - \partial_n u = 3 \cos(\varphi)^2 & \text{ if r $=$ 1}   
   \end{cases}
   $

I got the answer $u = P_0 (\cos(\theta)) - 2r^2 P_2 (\cos(\theta))$, where P is Legendre's polynomial.

But the right answer is $u = P_0 (\cos(\theta)) - 2r^2 P_2 (\cos(\theta)) + r Y_1 (\theta, \phi)$ where $Y_1$ is spherical function of order 1. How can I get the spherical function?

2. Find common solution of boundary value problem for Laplace's equation in a disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
   $
   \begin{cases}
   \Delta u = 0 & \text{ if r $<$ 1} \\
   u - \partial_n u = 2 \cos(\varphi)^2 & \text{ if r $=$ 1}   
   \end{cases}
   $

My answer is $u = 1 - r^2 \cos(2\varphi)$,

but the right answer is $u = 1 - r^2 \cos(2\varphi) + r (a\cos\varphi + b\sin\varphi)$ where $a$ and $b$ arbitrary constants.

Similarly, I do not understand how to get the last term.

3. At what ratio between $A$ and $B$ boundary problem for Laplace's equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has solutions? Find all of them.

$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = 0 & \text{ if 1 $<$ r $<$ 2} \\
\partial_n u |_{r=1} = A + 2 \cos\theta \\
\partial_n u |_{r=2} = B - 2 \cos\theta  
\end{cases}
$

Can you give me advice how to apply solvability condition to find this ratio or maybe I need to do something different here?